# Debug doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, debugging

I'm developing a Google App Engine App. I'd like to debug it, but I don't understand how, if breakpoint are set, python script in just ran. 
Suggestions?

Comment: Are you using python or java?

Comment: Sorry didn't spot that, I use logger entries but not in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it works in Python. In Java, if you're working with Eclipse, you just have to press Debug and it starts the Development Server. Then you just to open your browser and go to `http://localhost:8888` and that's it! It works perfectly with breakpoints and so on...

Comment: At least usign 8080 port. I know what to click in Eclipse to get debug started.